# How to interact with integer field in Django SQLite Database?

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-models

How to update an integer field in a SQLite DB managed with Django models?

Extract of my Django models :

```
class Event(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  [...]
  attendees = models.ManyToManyField(Attendee)
  max_attendees = 8
  #max_attendees = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Testing with `python3 manage.py shell`

```
>>> from main.models import *
>>> Event.objects.first()
<Event: 8 places left>
>>> Event.objects.first().max_attendees
8
>>> Event.objects.first().max_attendees = 2
>>> Event.objects.first().save()
>>> Event.objects.first().max_attendees
8
```

As you can see, the value is not updated even with a `save()` on the "object".

I have also tried :

```
>>> Event.objects.first().max_attendees = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(2)
```

But it's not updating the value of `max_attendees` either. How can I modify the value of this field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two issues. One, `max_attendees` is not a database field, it is a constant value. Change it to:

```
class Event(models.Model):
   ...
    max_attendees = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=8)
```

You may have to run `python manage makemigrations` and `python manage migrate` after this change.

Second, each time you call `Event.objects.first()` you are creating a new object using the existing database record. You should assign the instance to a variable and use that until you are finished, i.e:

```
>>> my_event = Event.objects.first()
>>> my_event.max_attendees = 2
>>> my_event.save()
```

You can then re-query the data written:

```
>>> Event.objects.first().max_attendees
```